# CSS to make App using 100% of height and width

Tags: html, css

I'm learning socket.io and I've built a chat app using it but I have problem getting the app to look good or even be usable.

I search for some terms online but seems in CSS there are 100 possible solutions for each problem so I'm not sure which is the best method to solve my issues, are some methods very old and now there are better/simpler options etc.

**Current HTML**

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-10">
      <div class="panel panel-primary">
        <div class="panel-heading">
          <h3 class="panel-title">Chat</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="panel-body">
          <ul id="messages"></ul>
        </div>
        <form>
          <div class="input-group">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="message" placeholder="Message" />
            <span class="input-group-btn">
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="send">Send</button>
            </span>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2">
      <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">
          <h3 class="panel-title">Users</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="panel-body">
          <div class="list-group" id="users"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Current screenshot**

[image]

I want it so that the 2 panels do not scroll beneath the users browser i.e. when the panels hit the edge of the browser the scrolling should happen inside the panel rather than going beneath the users browser.

I've tried using CSS:

```
.panel {
    height: 100vh;
    max-height: 100vh;
    position: relative;
}
.panel-body {
    overflow: auto;
    position: absolute;
    top: 40px;
    bottom: 15px;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
}
```

but this still shows a scroll bar on the browser (Google Chrome) and also the form is then at the top of the panel. I want the form to be at the bottom of the panel and the messages above to be scroll able.

**Fiddle**

http://www.bootply.com/hESm7L5klV

Comment: Can you add more css to your question or recreat the issue on jsfiddle?

Comment: @SamWillis The only custom CSS I am using I have already included, the rest is just Bootstrap. I'll add a fiddle.

Comment: `margin-bottom` on `.pannel`

Answer (score 1):

`margin-bottom` on `.pannel` Is pushing your height further down as margin is -excluded from the heights and so is added onto the `100vh` you already set.

Simply add `margin-bottom: 0;` to the class: `.panel`

Comment: I don't set `margin:bottom` so guess that is done by Bootstrap. What is the answer?

Comment: Simply add `margin-bottom: 0;` to the class: `.panel` where you already have set the `height: 100vh`

Comment: Thanks! Do you know about the second question? When I add the custom CSS the form shoots to the top, by default in Bootstrap it is at the bottom. I don't know what CSS to use, or where I would find this?

Comment: So you want the chat to be stuck to the bottom of the page? By adding the height to panel you are setting your chat to take up the whole page size available.

Comment: No I want the message form to be stuck to the bottom of the panel, and the chat messages to be above it and scrollable.

Comment: Ah, if you add `position: absolute; bottom: 0;` to the form with css then it will work

Answer (score 0):

For scrollable content but fixed rest:

```
.panel {
    margin-bottom: 0;
    min-height: 100vh;
    position: relative;
}
.panel-body {
    max-height: 100vh;
    margin-bottom: -41px; // substract height of panel-footer
    overflow: scroll;
    padding-bottom: 100px;
}
.panel-footer {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

[See this fiddle](http://www.bootply.com/Q1UDu2kwta)

Comment: If only the messages container should be scrollable you need overflow, yes.